# Moved Zend Framework project to Ubuntu and it stopped working

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, zend-framework-modules

I have a Zend Framework project that I started working on a a while back in Windows. It was run on Zend Server CE and everything worked fine. Moving it between Windows machines was no problem at all. But now I wanted to put it on a Ubuntu Server, still using Zend Server CE. But it started to complain about missing Controller Plugins. But they were located at the "correct" spot. I guess the autoloader is somehow getting confused.

Feels like it should be the fact that Windows uses case-insensitive names on folders and files that be the cause. Which folders does Zend Framework need to have in the correct case?
Looking at standard project layout's lowercase names for folders are used. But looking at the Zend Framework itself capital first letters are used. Maybe together with the fact that the Zend Framework autoloader accepts singular class names on a plural form folder name like

`Form_Foo` being located in `forms/Foo.php`

In my project the main part of the project uses the standard lowercase style.

ie

```
application
  modules
    default
      controllers
      views
      models
      forms
      plugins
        controller
          acl
            Plugin.php  -- The class Plugin_Controller_Acl_Plugin in this file is not found on Linux
    foo
      controlles
      views
      models
      forms
```

But then in my library folder I have a Core folder where I have my Core classes and on those I use the Zend Framework way of naming them

```
library
  Core
    Model
      User.php -- Contains the class Core_Model_User
```

Quick tests seem to indicate that Zend Framework is able to locate these classes just fine.

When in Zend Framework in Linux, where do you have to use correct case names for the autoloading to work? Should one opt for first capital names throughout like

```
Application
  Modules
    Default
      Controllers
      Views
      ...
```

Any ideas and tips are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "Plugin_Controller_Acl_Plugin" the only class which cannot be loaded? If so, you should try using uppercase for every directory inside plugins (like plugins/Controller/Acl), because the autoloader only associates the "Plugin_" part of the namespace with the "plugins" directory, the others will be loaded just as the other classes (Uppercase directory names remain, only the underscores will be converted to directory separator). Take a look at Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader for the default settings, you should use uppercase directory names under the directories listed there (forms, plugins, etc.).

Comment: Yea.. it was the stupidity of windows lower/uppercase ignorance that caused it all :)